# Create Folder with the folder name as desired user on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, directory, create-directory

How do I create a folder in the application package to the user folder name as you wish? After clicking createBtn, it will display a pop up for the user to type the folder name in accordance with the wishes of the user. After clicking OKBtn will create a folder on the local package matches the name typed earlier.

XAML:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="createBtn" Icon="Folder" Label="Tambah Folder" Foreground="White" Click="createBtn_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a folder in the application package. The app package is read only and shared amongst users.

If you want to have the user choose a folder then use a [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) and let the user choose a folder anywhere she has access. Save the returned StorageFolder in a [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) so that the app can access it later without the user having to pick it again.

See [Quickstart: Accessing files with file pickers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771180(v=win.10)) for examples.

We'll need a StorageFolder to track the folder the user picked, and a token to identify the item in the FutureAccessList so it can be retrieved later.

```
StorageFolder folder;
string accessToken;
```

And a quick code snippet to pick and remember the folder:

```
FolderPicker fp= new FolderPicker();
fp.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

folder = await fp.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
   accessToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList.add(folder);
}
```

Comment: i mean is in local package. Not using folder picker. But I want the user to create a folder named according to the wishes of the user. The folder is displayed in a gridview.

Comment: The app package is not writeable so you can't create a folder there. You can create a folder in local user data with ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("myfoldername");

Comment: how to create a folder named according to the wishes of the user? When user clicked createBtn, it will display a pop up for the user to type the folder name in accordance with the wishes of the user. After clicking OKBtn will create a folder that matches the name typed earlier.